# Backdrop in xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to create backdrop for pop up window.

By backdrop I mean semi transparent background which is behind popup and stretches on a whole application screen. This makes the popout window more dominant and blocks the possibility to click on anything else in the background.

It would be best if popup window xaml code is deep inside the structure of the view if possible. Not at the top of hierarchy or bottom.

My issue with this is that the backdrop size wont stretch over its parents size.

So if my view is 
1000x1000
My content in view is 
500x500
and my pop up window is in this 500x500 it wont stretch over this size.

I tried with Position absolute, relative, translatin x/y, adjusting margins to high values to get bigger size.

I just cant get it done.

Example
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Plugin [PopupPage](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) .And set the layout of popup as you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    x:Class="MyProject.MyPopupPage">
    <!--You can set an animation in the xaml file or in the csharp code behind-->
    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation 
            PositionIn="Center"
            PositionOut="Center"
            ScaleIn="1.2"
            ScaleOut="0.8"
            DurationIn="400"
            DurationOut="300"
            EasingIn="SinOut"
            EasingOut="SinIn"
            HasBackgroundAnimation="True"/>
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <!--You can use any elements here which are extended from Xamarin.Forms.View-->
    <StackLayout 
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
        Padding="20, 20, 20, 20">
        //...
    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

And for more details you can check https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/Getting-started